# Not sure which data structure to use

Tags: c++, data-structures

Assuming I have the following text:

```
today was a good day and today was a sunny day.
```

I break up this text into lines, seperated by white spaces, which is

```
Today

was

a

good
```

etc.

Now I use the vector data structure to simple count the number of words in a text via .size(). That's done.

However, I also want to check If a word comes up more than once, and if so, how many time. In my example "today" comes up 2 times.

I want to store that "today" and append a 2/x (depending how often it comes up in a large text). Now that's not just for "today" but for every word in the text. I want to look up how often a word appears, append an counter, and sort it (the word + counters) in descending order (that's another thing, but
not important right now).

I'm not sure which data structure to use here. Map perhaps? But I can't add counters to map.

Edit: This is what I've done so far: http://pastebin.com/JncR4kw9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a map. Infact, you should use an `unordered_map`.

`unordered_map<string,int>` will give you a hash table which will use strings as keys, and you can augment the integer to keep count.

`unordered_map` has the advantage of O(1) lookup and insertion over the O(logn) lookup and insertion of a `map`. This is because the former uses an array as a container whereas the latter uses some implementation of trees (red black, I think).

The only disadvantage of an `unordered_map` is that as mentioned in its name, you can't iterate over all the elements in lexical order. This should be clear from the explanation of their structure above. However, you don't seem to need such a traversal, and hence it shouldn't be an issue.

```
unordered_map<string,int> mymap;
mymap[word]++; // will increment the counter associated with the count of a word.
```

Comment: but I could do a sort(vector.begin(),vector.end()) before and then add them to unordered_map, which would already be ordered due to sort, no?

Comment: Ah, nice, this worked. Got my code working. Now onto math functions like sorting in descending order...

Answer (score 2):

Why not use *two* data structures? The vector you have now, and a [*map*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), using the string as the key, and an integer as data, which then will be the number of times the word was found in the text.

Comment: two containers is often a good idea if you want both fast search for elements/counts and iterate the data or preserve the initial order. In this case, the second container may only keep iterators of the other, which requires, of course, the use of a container that preserves iterators ...

Comment: Could you give me an example code please? I've had something like that in mind. Using my vector, sorted with sort() before, and added to map. I'm just not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

Sort the vector in alphabetical order.
Scan it and compare every word to those that follow, until you find a different one, and son on.

```
a, a, and, day, day, sunny, today, today, was, was
2     1    2         1      2             2
```

Answer (score 0):

A better option to consider is Radix Tree, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree
Which is quite memory efficient, and in case of large text input, it will perform better than alternative data structures.

One can store the frequencies of a word in the nodes of tree. Also it will reap the benefits of "locality of reference[For any text document]" too.